# color rescaling in java of buffered image

Tags: java, colors, scaling

First of all, thanks for reading.

I am writing a class which returns an image from 2D double array(kDEvalue from the code).
However, since so many values(256*256) vary in a very small range(-1 to 1), i cannot use the default color scaling(it is all black if i use the value from the array).

```
 BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(kDEvalues.length, kDEvalues[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
                image.setRGB(x, y, (255*(int)Math.round(kDEvalues[x][y]))/100);
            }
        }


        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("CustomImage.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In this case, how I rescale the color in grey scale so that I can see the varience of the value? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right here:

> image.setRGB(x, y, (255*(int)Math.round(kDEvalues[x][y]))/100);

There are three things wrong with your expression for the RGB value. First, you round and then multiply. This drops any fractions of your small values, it should be the other way around. Second you only create a value for one color channel (the blue one) and thrid, you do not check for overflow.

Try something like this:

```
int gray = (int) Math.round((kDEvalues[x][y] - (-1)) * 127.5);
// limit range to 0-255
gray = Math.min(gray, 255);
gray = Math.max(gray, 0);
// copy gray value to r, g and b channel
int rgb = (gray << 16) | (gray << 8) | gray;
image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
```

First operation is to scale the value to 0-255. Since you say your values are in range -1 to 1, adjust the values so the lower bound falls on zero (by subtracting the lower bound). Then multiply by a factor that the highes value becomes 255 (thats (1 - (-1)) * 127.5 = 255).

Just to be safe, clip the resulting value to 0-255 (Math.min/max expressions).

Then replicate the gray value in RGB by setting the gray value to all 3 color channels. The format is documented in the javadoc and the bit shifts just place the gray value at the correct position within the int.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now it is all gray. I think the range is much smaller than I mentioned above. It is 0 to -1E-3